# Dockerized Elasticsearch with CORS support

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, cors

I'm trying to set up a local Elasticsearch instance for development purposes. So, I started with a basic docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.7.1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node # Runs as a single-node
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms256m -Xmx256m'
      network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
      xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
    volumes: # Stores elasticsearch data locally on the esdata Docker volume
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - internal
      - elastic

# Define the Docker volume named esdata for the Elasticsearch container.
volumes:
  esdata:
# Networks to use
networks:
  elastic:
    external: true
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

This works fine, in order to test a WordPress plugin that uses Elasticsearch. However, now I need to avoid CORS related errors, so I tried to add parameters to the environment:

```
  http.cors.enabled: 'true'
  http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
  http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
  http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept
  http.cors.allow-credentials: 'true'
```

This doesn't work. The Elasticsearch refuses connections after applying the changes.

So, what I need is to have minimal security but allowing at the same time CORS request from anywhere.

Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Elasticsearch and Wordpress. I'm assuming you're using [ElasticPress](https://www.elasticpress.io/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing Elasticpress in my local environment, but the problem I'm facing must be addressed on the Elasticsearch side.

Comment: Correct. I ask because I had some issues with figuring out some of the finer networking details concerning both CORS as well as TLS, and I too was using ElasticPress. As far as CORS issues goes, what is generating the CORS error? Are you getting the error from the Autocomplete component? Or from attempting to configure Elasticsearch itself?

Comment: I'm trying to use the autosuggest feature with a local instance of Elasticpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting CORS errors due to the fact that the Autosuggest feature of Elasticpress is a frontend concept, and the backend URL doesn't match that of the frontend.

You really should be keeping your Elasticsearch Cluster completely private, and keep communications with it limited to network requests.

That said, since Autosuggest requires the use of a public-facing endpoint, we've gotten around this by proxying an endpoint using NGINX in the following way:

```
location /es-search {
    limit_except POST {
        deny all;
    }
    rewrite ^/es-search <desired-es-index-here>/_search break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # Only enable if you're using Authentication with your ES Cluster
    # proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic <Base64EncodedPasswordHere>";
    proxy_pass https://elasticsearch:9200; # Whatever your internal DNS name or IP address is for your ES Cluster goes here
}
```

By doing it this way, we expose an `/es-search` endpoint for public consumption, and allow the server to authenticate with Elasticsearch itself. This way, all requests become internal, and there won't be any need for monkeying around with your CORS settings.

Feel free to use this as a launchpad and fill in your network details for anything between the angle brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @maiorano84 . I will give it a try. Just a question: Given your suggested Nginx setup, how the autosuggest endpoint URL should look like? Best regards.

Comment: Basically, the autosuggest endpoint would match the domain your Wordpress site is operating under. So let's say your site is `https://my-domain.com`, the above configuration would create an autosuggest endpoint for you at `https://my-domain.com/es-search`.

Comment: This solution works fine on my local development environment, where I have total control of the Nginx configuration. Thanks. I wonder if there is a way to apply the same solution on production, considering that my hosting provider (Cloudways) uses Apache instead of Nginx and the .htaccess file is the only thing under my control. Best regards.

Comment: @Javerleo Apache has similar ProxyPass directives, but they won't work in an .htaccess context unfortunately. You may need to contact Cloudways support to see if they can make the adjustment on the server for you, or at least provide you with root/sudo access to the server via SSH or some kind of interactive shell so you can make the adjustment to the Apache Configs yourself.